# .Net Restful POST with Actionscript

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3, rest

I am trying to create a method in actionscript to call a Restful service in .Net. The method is:

```
public function executeService(serviceName:String):void
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(serviceName);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    configureListeners(urlLoader);

    urlLoader.load(request);
}
```

The Restful Interface looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "Authenticate1")]
XElement Authenticate1();
```

And the Implementation of this interface looks like this:

```
public XElement Authenticate1()
{
    return new XElement("<Root>");
}
```

But when I run the actionscript code it returns I/O error:

```
Error #2032: Stream Error.
```

I am not sure what is wrong in this code, any help will be appreciated.

If I change the Method value to GET in Restful service interface, then the same URL can be accessed by web browser. So I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the URL. Of course I will add the url variables once this thing works.

Thanks

**Update:**
When I call this service from Fiddler, it works.

Comment: Use Fiddler and see what is send between browser and server. Most likely you'll see your problem. At least you'll be able to provide better information in the post.

Comment: The error is: Method not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here from mlavie: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/746809

If "request.data" is empty ("") or null, then "request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST" is ignored, and a GET verb is issued. I do not see that documented anywhere, and in my humble opinion this is a bug. It is totally legitimate to send "request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST" with an empty body. Some webservices will have no input required and certainly a "dumb" web page containing static XML requires no input to render itself.